# How to persist Java8 LocalDate / LocalDateTime with ORM Lite?

Tags: java, ormlite, java-time

How to persist and recover objects with LocalDate or LocalDateTime in it's attributes, using ORMLite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to persist and recover objects with LocalDate or LocalDateTime in it's attributes, using ORMLite?

I'd use a [`CustomPersister`](http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-persister) which allows you to define how your field should be persisted if its not a "standard" java field.

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = LocalDateTimePersister.class)
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

You should take a look at the
[DateTimeType class](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/DateTimeType.java) that persists the JodaTime `DateTime` as an example on how to write them.